# Sort(); method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

When using the sort method in JavaScript, it doesn't give me the right result. What could be the reason for this? Code below and its output:

```
let numbers = [14, -124, 68, 2, 56, -111, 0, 69, 9];
numbers.sort();
console.log(numbers);
```

**Output:** [-111, -124, 0, 14, 2, 56, 68, 69, 9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let numbers = [14, -124, 68, 2, 56, -111, 0, 69, 9];
numbers = numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(numbers);
```

->

```
[
  -124, -111,  0,  2,
     9,   14, 56, 68,
    69
]
```

The default sorting is alphabetical unfortunately

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates, especially ones that have comments on them saying "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link to a duplicate question.

Comment: "This question already has answers here" was not there at the time I was writing my answer

Comment: comments on them saying "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link to a duplicate question.